# Server listening

Tags: vb.net, authentication, client, ip, broadcast

**I'm working with VB.NET**

So I have a server that broadcast it's own IP every second

```
Private Sub IPBroadcastTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles IPBroadcastTimer.Tick
        BroadcastIP()
End Sub
```

Do I have to keep broadcasting it every second for clients to pick it up after several minutes or hours?

If so, how would I set the server to listen to logins?

Here's what happens client-side and server-side:

Server : **"Broadcasts IP every second"** > **"Listens to incoming transmissions"** > **"receives 3 strings *[username/pass/ip]*"** > **"Checks username and password validity on local XML file"** > **"sends confirmation or denial to target IP"**

Client : **"Listens to server broadcast"** > **"Receives Server IP"** > **"Sends 3 Strings through a form: username, password and local IP"** > **"Listen to server's confirmation or denial"**

I used this to send, but listening doesn't seem to work...

```
Public EndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255"), 1001) ''Send destination port
Public EndPoint2 As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2001) ''Receive destination port
Public UserIPEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2001)
Public UsernameEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2001)
Public PassEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2001)

Public Send As New UdpClient(2001) ''Send source port
Public Receive As New UdpClient(1001) '' Receive source port
```

Sending:

```
Send.Send(IPInBytes, IPInBytes.Length, EndPoint)
```

Receiving:

```
Receive.Receive(UserIPEndPoint)
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the broadcast? If it is for consumers to detect the service, perhaps it's better to rely on already developed protocols for this (such as [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) or [SSDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol)). Like in at least SSDP, a consumer can broadcast a question ("is anybody there?") to which services may reply. Services may also spontaneously broadcast their presence, for instance when they are started, so that consumers with an ongoing detection can find them.

Comment: Well I don't know how SSDP works, mind guiding me a bit through?